# Авторизация по mac через порт api в php

Tags: php, api, роутер, mikrotik

Авторизация через через php на порт api происходит через ip, логин и пароль.

Как возможно реализовать подключение через php на порт api путем замены ip адреса на mac адрес?

Через терминал другого микротика, можно реализовать подключение 
`tool mac-telnet 00:00:00:00:00:00`. Как в реализовать в php и возможно ли это вообще!?

Comment: php про mac, ip ничего не знает и не должен знать, ему все данные присылает веб сервер

Comment: по сути, я хочу реализовать соединение по mac, как winbox подключается по ip или mac! Хочу перевести это в php, по ip это реализовано, а как по mac? неизвестно!

Comment: Думаю стоит почитать здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Comment: @Walfter Все эти переменные заполняются веб сервером, нужно знать как настроен в микротике он

Comment: @weyners это на форумы с микротиком

Comment: @Ghost собственно об этом и говорится в том ответе, только там есть варик читать мак если находится в локальной сети

Answer (score 0):

Mikrotik используют свой собственный протокол для реализации telnet по MAC-адресу. Существует [open-source реализация](https://github.com/haakonnessjoen/MAC-Telnet) этого протокола на C.

Про реализацию на PHP я ничего не слышал, но есть [описание протокола](https://omniflux.com/devel/mikrotik/Mikrotik_MAC_Telnet_Procotol.txt), можете попробовать реализовать свой клиент.